After upgrading WordPress, I am getting the following error. Error message: cURL error 52: Empty reply from server
I had WordPress version version 6.4.4 (as best I can recall) and upgraded to version 6.5.3.That seemed to go well. I then started to upgrade the networks. It got the 4th one and thru the following error.
"Warning! Problem updating https://site.example.com/user4. Your server may not be able to connect to sites running on it. Error message: cURL error 52: Empty reply from server".
I tried reload the page to make it do the upgrade again but I get the same error at the same place. When I go to that site in a browser, there is a site there. Not much, but there is data there.
The network update stops completely at that error.
I am not sure what to do from here. Please help.
MY
